# How to create a dynamic matrix in lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to work with some matrix in lua for my dungeon generator. Basically I'll have matrix [x][y] and a structure inside there will store the info of each "room". But since it is a generator, I don't know how many rooms I'll have, and the only way I know is to make something like this:

```
mat = {}
for i = 0, 10 do
    mat[i] = {}
    for j = 0, 10 do
        mat[i][j] = 1
    end
end
```

So the question is, is there a way to create a matrix that dynamic increases the size as I add data to it? because there will be blank spaces since the dungeon is going to be like a tree branch.

Comment: Lua tables are dynamic by nature. They don't have a fixed size.

Comment: This is tables of tables. Similar to "ragged arrays" in other languages, except that a table is not an array. (If you want "array length" and other array-like properties, you have to keep the table a "[sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7)", which is more restrictive than an "array".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Programming in Lua:

> Moreover, tables have no fixed size; you can add as many elements as
>   you want to a table dynamically.

To handle access to non-existent table members and so avoid error messages for indexing nil values you can use a metatable implementing the __index metamethod.

In the following example Lua will insert an empty table into your table whenever it is not there yet.

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4 for details

```
local mt_2D = {
   __index =
      function(t, k)
         local inner = {}
         rawset(t, k, inner)
         return inner
      end
}
local array2D = setmetatable({}, mt_2D)

array2D[2][5] = 'it works'

print(array2D[2][5])    -->  it works
```

Comment: are there any examples how I can run throught all values inserted on this table?

Comment: @Paulix - `for x, t in pairs(array2D) do for y, value in pairs(t) do print(x, y, value) end end`